# Explanation for a exercise using the L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

So, I have this equation:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} x^x
$$
and the solution:
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+} (e^{\log x})^x = \lim_{x\to0^+} e^{x\log x} = e^{\lim_{x\to0^+}x\log x} = 1
$$

What I don't understand is why is $$\lim_{x\to0^+}x^x = \lim_{x\to0^+}e^{x\log x}$$
Thank you a lot!

Comment: Check the definition of $a^x$.

Comment: I know that $0^0$ is not defined but I still I don't understand the  transformation

Comment: Do you know the definition of $2^x$?

Comment: well, the basis is 2 and the exponent is the one that is changing into whatever number and it means that the 2 is multiplying itself x times $2^1 = 2; 2^2 = 2 * 2 ... $

Comment: What about $2^\pi$?

Comment: well I do have a bit of a problem solving that

Comment: When in calculus, you shouldn't look at $x^y$ with $x>0, y\not \in \mathbb Z$ as $\underbrace{x\cdot \ldots \cdot x}_{y\text{ factors}}$, but rather as $e^{y\log (x)}$ (you can take it as the definition of $x^y$). Until you tell us how it was that $a^x$ was defined, you can't expect much better answers than the ones below.

Comment: I did some reading, and I found and read the definition, thank you a lot. It is really a lot clearer to me now

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12428/discussion-between-mark-and-git-gud)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See from the logarithmic laws we can write a= e^(ln(a)) [where ln is nothing but the log to the base 'e'.when the base is **'e'**, the **log** can be written as **'ln'** it is called natural logarithm or the **nepoleonic logarithm** it is implied that the base is **'e'** we just write **ln3, means log of 3 to the base 'e'**

Now if we write e^(ln 3), it is nothing but 3.
e is powerd by the number (ln3) right! it is nothing but 3 is the answer.
 let us prove that: let
                              X=e^(ln 3)

```
                     or, ln(X)=ln(e^(ln 3))          [taking ln on both side]

                     or, ln(X)=(ln 3)*(ln(e))             [note that lne is equal to 1]

                     or, ln(X)= (ln 3)*1

                     or, X=3                     [removing ln from both side]
```

we assumed X= e^(ln 3) and here we got X=3.
so, 
     e^(ln 3) is nothing but actually 3! :-)

**similarly you can understand x^x can be written as e^(ln (x^x)) or e^(x*ln x)) as we know that ln (3^2) is nothing but 2*(ln 3). 
I think this discussion will help you.best of luck.

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough explanation!

Comment: I think you mean "Nap(i)erian logarithm" and not "napoleonic logarithm".

Answer (score 3):

$$a^x=b, a\neq 1, a>0\to x=\log_a(b)$$ This means that under proper conditions the functions $f(x)=a^x,~~ g(x)=\log_a(x)$ are inverse to each other. Moreover,  there is a simple rule for logarithm that says $a\log(b)=\log(b^a), b>0$. If you are asking about $$\lim\exp(*)=\exp(\lim(*))$$ I can say that we are allowed to do this cause the function $\exp(x)$ is always continuous over real line.

Comment: What is the exact name of this rule (limit interchange?)

Answer (score 1):

Because $x > 0$ in the limit, $\log (x) $ is well-defined. From the rule $$a^b = e^{b \log a}$$ we get (with $a=b=x$) $$x^x = e^{x \log x}$$